# What single transformation is equivalent with the composition

Tags: geometry, transformation

I am trying to figure out the single transformation that is equivalent to the below composition.

A glide reflection by vector $\langle−1, 1\rangle$ and reflection line $y = −x+1$, followed by translation vector $\langle−2, −2\rangle$.

$T_{\langle-2,-2\rangle}$ $∘\ G_{\langle-1,1\rangle,y=-x+1}$

This is what I have come up with.  Hopefully I did this correctly.  Please let me know.

$\ M_{y=-x-1}$ $∘\ M_{y=-x+1}$$∘\ M_{y=-x+1}$$∘\ T_{\langle-1,1\rangle}$
$\ M_{y=-x-1}$ $∘\ T_{\langle-1,-1\rangle}$
$\ G_{\langle-1,1\rangle,y=-x-1}$

Comment: Yes it is correct, but don't understand how you get it.